# How to get timezone offset to correctly display on 24h format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, momentjs

I'm running into an issue where my app is being accessed from different parts of the world. And, I have a chart to display peak access times. If accessed from a different part of the world (than the origin) I need it to reflect the converted origin time. However, the way it is currently set up, the calculation renders `fooPoint.hour` with the value of for example `28` instead of `00:03` (am).
I can pinpoint that this occurs in the `else` conditional, since, for example, if they would be Accessing from Australia, with a `fooPoint.hour = 20` and `this.state.timeZoneOffset = -8`. `20 - (-8) = 28` and I would like it to display as `00:04`. I know my calculations are wrong, so can anyone help me format this correctly please?

I failed to mention that `fooPoint.hour` is actually a data point I get in the `foo` object (which is fetched from an API), so that represents the avg. peak time of certain location. When viewed from another location in a different part of the world, I need to take into account the time zone difference to display in the chart the peak time but on their time zone

Is a library a low technical debt solution?

I have this array of objects as such:

```
foo: {
  hour: 20
}
```

I obtain the timezone offset as such:
`let tzOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;`
and store it in state

Then I have:

```
foo.forEach((fooPoint) => {
  fooPoint.hour = 
     fooPoint.hour - this.state.timeZoneOffset < 0
     ? fooPoint.hour - this.state.timeZoneOffset + 24
     : foorPoint.hour - this.state.timeZoneOffset;
});
```

Comment: Is the [date locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) not enough?

Comment: @AlexisWilke thanks for your response! I failed to mention that `fooPoint.hour` is actually a data point I get in the `foo` object, so that represets the avg. peak time of certain location. When viewded from another location around the world, I need to take into account the time zone difference to display in the chart the peak time but on their time zone.

Comment: I'm not clear why 28 should display as 00:03 and not 04:00.  I get that 28 or 28:00 is wrong.  What I don't get is why 00:03 is right.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it should be 00:04 @mdfst13 ! That was a miscalculation on my side

Comment: You still have it wrong... you put `00:04` instead of `04:00`...

Comment: Yea I wrote it wrong in the comment, have butterfinget today :P, but had did correct it the right way in the actualpost. Anyways, do you guys have any ideas lol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two possible conditions that you want to fix:

1. The timezone offset takes an early morning time and produces a negative result.  I believe that your code will handle that.
2. The timezone offset takes a late evening result and makes it higher than 24.  Your code is missing this adjustment.

Try

```
foo.forEach((fooPoint) => {
  fooPoint.hour -= this.state.timeZoneOffset;
  fooPoint.hour = 
     fooPoint.hour < 0
     ? fooPoint.hour + 24
     : foorPoint.hour >= 24
       ? fooPoint.hour - 24
       : fooPoint.hour;
});
```

Moving the subtraction out is just because I'm lazy and don't want to repeat it five times.

The critical part here is to test for both possibilities.

You might also find it more readable as `if` statements.

```
foo.forEach((fooPoint) => {
    fooPoint.hour -= this.state.timeZoneOffset;
    if (fooPoint.hour < 0) {
        fooPoint.hour += 24;
    } else if (fooPoint.hour >= 24) {
        fooPoint.hour -= 24;
    }
});
```

The two are functionally the same, but many would find that easier to follow.